# how can i alternate between 0 and 1 values in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I want to create a select which will alternate between 1 and 0

my table looks like that

```
id1    id2    al
11     1      1
40     1      0
12     1      0
237    1      1
```

but I want to make it like that

```
id1    id2    al
40     1      0
11     1      1
12     1      0
237    1      1
```

I want to keep the same values in my table but I just want to switch the rows to alternate between 0 and 1

Comment: what is the purpose here?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu it's for a code after that. Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
select *
from mytable
order by row_number() over(partition by al order by id1), al
```

This alternates `0` and `1` values - if the groups have a different number of rows, then, once the smallest group exhausts, all remaining rows in the other group appear at the end of the resultset.

I am unsure which column you want to use to order the rows within each group - I assumed `id1`, but you might want to change that to your actual requirement.